# Virtualization not enabled error in docker even though it is enabled

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I try to install docker toolbox on Windows 10 Home 64 bit. I've got an AMD cpu. 
Windows 10 home edition doesn't have Hyper-V feature, so it cannot be enabled, but just to be sure, I tried to disable it (windows wasn't able to recognize this feature).

I also enabled virtualization in BIOS, I restarted my machine multiple times, I can see in system properties that virtualization is enabled.
I even reinstalled docker toolbox (I'm using version 18.09.3).
I have installed latest VirtualBox (5.2.28r)
And I still get an error

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...
    enter code here
```

Are you able to tell me what I'm doing wrong or what else I could try ?